# javascript catch function call

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I *catch (trigger event)* when a certain function in a *big, uneditable* library is called?

```
// big js library
var biglibrary = {
    runme: function(arguments){
        // do something...
    },
    otherfunctions: function(.....
}
```

Now how can I *outside above* catch / notice when *runme* is called? Can I? I tried something like this ->

```
$(biglibrary).on('runme', function(){
    // function was called !!!
});
```

Answer (score 3):

In the vast majority of cases, you can *wrap* the function:

```
const original = biglibrary.runme;
biglibrary.runme = function(...args) {
    console.log("Function was called!");
    return original.apply(this, args);
};
```

```js
const biglibrary = {
    runme: function(a, b) {
        console.log(`Original function: ${a} + ${b}`);
        return a + b;
    },
};

const original = biglibrary.runme;
biglibrary.runme = function(...args) {
    console.log("Function was called!");
    return original.apply(this, args);
}

console.log(biglibrary.runme(1, 2));
```

This is sometimes called "monkey-patching."

In some cases, the library may have made the `runme` property read-only, in which case you *might* be able to wrap it via `Object.defineProperty`:

```
const original = biglibrary.runme;
const descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(biglibrary, "runme");
descr.value = function(...args) {
    console.log("Function was called!");
    return original.apply(this, args);
}
Object.defineProperty(biglibrary, "runme", descr);
```

```js
const biglibrary = {
    runme: function(a, b) {
        console.log(`Original function: ${a} + ${b}`);
        return a + b;
    },
};

const original = biglibrary.runme;
const descr = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(biglibrary, "runme");
descr.value = function(...args) {
    console.log("Function was called!");
    return original.apply(this, args);
}
Object.defineProperty(biglibrary, "runme", descr);

console.log(biglibrary.runme(1, 2));
```

If the library has made the property both read-only *and* non-configurable, you can't wrap it, but that's rare.